# Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp

I am developing a script to create/update group/team sites from a SharePoint list. I have everything working, but I am struggling big time with authentication.

I use

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://client.sharepoint.com/sites/testclientsite -UseWebLogin -Scopes "Group.ReadWrite.All","Directory.Read.All"
```

In order to `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate`.

Anytime I am switching from the list and the newly created site to apply the template, I use

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://client.sharepoint.com/sites/sharepointlist -UseWebLogin
```

To connect to SP List of clients

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://client.sharepoint.com/sites/newsite -UseWebLogin
```

To connect to new site to apply template.

This works amazing through the first one or two sites, then I receive a

> Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

It is somewhat random. Sometimes it will make it through one or two sites. I have also had it work through 8 or so sites before it errors out. I am assuming it has something to do with the token expiring, but I am not positive. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I use 'service account' to do this instead of using UseWebLogin each time.

Hope it helps you.

```
#region Variables 
$Username = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
$Password = "password" 
$siteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/wiki" 

#endregion Variables

#region Credentials 
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass) 
#endregion Credentials

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials

Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path "C:\Lee\Script\template.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, but I figured out my issue. When I created the group, I was not giving enough time to create the SP site for the group.Since the site has not been created yet, I get a 403. I just put a "pause"

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 180
```

The pause solved my issue and allowed me to use -useweblogin

Thanks